# Entry() Is not showing up in my program

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am having trouble figuring out why my Entry() is not showing up in my program window. I have looked around the internet and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to place my Entry() field above my main text filed in the program but at this point I would settle for it showing up at all in the program.

The code works fine except for the EntryWidget I am tying to add in.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import subprocess as sub
import tkinter.messagebox

#use the doNothing function as a holder for anything that needs to call a function you have not made yet

def doNothing():
    print("Do lots of nothing?")

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Message Box >~~~~~~~~~~~

def ihnb():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("This is an example!", "Icecream Has No Bones!")
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("This is not a real question", "Are you trying to become a programer?")
    if answer == "yes":
        a1 = "Then be prepared to spend countless hours hating life!"
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, a1)
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    else:
        a2= "Smart move. Now go away!"
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, a2)
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)



#create the window
root = Tk()
#modify root window
root.title("MINT:   Mobile Information & Note-taking Tool")
root.geometry("800x600")
root.config(bg = 'Orange')

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Entry Widget >~~~~~~~~~~~
keywordEntry = Entry(root)
keywordEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
keywordEntry.delete(0, END)
keywordEntry.insert(END, 'default text')

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Menu >~~~~~~~~~~~
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=doNothing)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=doNothing)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command= doNothing)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Info", command=doNothing)

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Toolbar >~~~~~~~~~~~
spacer10 = "          "
toolbar = Frame(root)

somethingButt = tkinter.Button(toolbar, fg = 'Black', bg = 'Orange', text = "Do Python?", command = ihnb)
somethingButt.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)
buttonSpacer0_1 = tkinter.Button(toolbar, fg = 'Black', bg = 'Black', text = spacer10)
buttonSpacer0_1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)
somethingButt2 = tkinter.Button(toolbar, fg = 'White', bg = 'Black', text = "Do something?", command = doNothing)
somethingButt2.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)
buttonSpacer0_1 = tkinter.Button(toolbar, fg = 'Black', bg = 'Black', text = spacer10)
buttonSpacer0_1.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)
somethingButt3 = tkinter.Button(toolbar, fg = 'White', bg = 'Black', text = "Do something?", command = doNothing)
somethingButt3.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

toolbar.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Toolbar >~~~~~~~~~~~

root.text = Text (root, width = 100, height = 10, fg='White', bg='Black', wrap = WORD)
root.text.grid(row = 10, padx=5, pady=5)

#~~~~~~~~~~~< Status Bar >~~~~~~~~~~~

status = Label(root, text = "Preparing to do nothing...", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = W)
status.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, I've executed your program on Ubuntu and I can see the Entry widget

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It might work in linux but it was not working for me in windows. I had to change the grid parameters for it to show up. Thanks to Billal BEGUERADJ input it now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to place my Entry() field above my main text filed

I think this is what you are looking for:

[image]

If so, then simply change:

```
keywordEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

To:

```
keywordEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Nota Bene:  This just resolves your problem, but there are other things to improve in your program.

Comment: Ok so changing to row 1 column 0 worked but can you explain why?

Comment: That solves the problem simply because you place `toolbar` widget on the row number 0. So all what you have to do is to place the entry widget beneath, meaning on row number 1 and more importanly changing the column number to 0 is what really fixes the trouble @BaconTech

Comment: I should have realized that. I thought the toolbar had its  own grid outside of the main window for some reason. Thanks for the info. Still new to this. Only been learning tkinter for about a week now.

Comment: The toolbar has its own grid to place its own components, but then the toolbar itself is placed in the grid of `root`. Do not forget to specify the column on which you position the toolbar though (I mean write: `toolbar.grid(row = 0, column=0, sticky = W)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did run into a new problem but I will try to work that one out myself for a while. I will make sure that my toolbar.grid is set up.